# C# ASP.NET MVC Using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just started using C# ASP.Net MVC. What I am trying to do is a register form using C# ASP.NET MVC, how do I save the data from the register from into XML format instead of a database?

I was unable to find any example online on this.

Currently, I have no code to show on this question.

Comment: Assuming there are multiple concurrent users using your website, storing data to XML could be problematic, XML files are not meant to be written concurrently. Please review your approach or provide more information about your specific scenario.

Comment: XML files are still text files, nothing more. There are *millions* of articles and blog posts on XML in .NET but very few try to use an XML or CSV or any other single file as a database. You can't insert text in the middle of a text file, you have to rewrite everything from the insertion point to the end. You can't modify anything unless the new text has exactly the same size as the old. You can append text, but XML only allows a single root per document. You'd have to read the entire file, modify it and then write it back. It would be easier to use a simpler format like CSV than XML

Comment: To answer your *exact* question, you do it the same way all tutorials show. You deserialize the XML file into a matching object, eg one containing a list of users, add a new user object to that list, then save the object over the previous file. Only *one* thread can do that at a time which makes this unsuitable for web applications

Comment: I am doing this for a school assignment, so one of the extra requirements is to save the data in the register form to an XML file instead of a database and retrieve the data to use for the login form.

Comment: This can be done. It is ok if you have only few tables in your dataset and you do not have concurrent users for registration form. However, writing data into XML file is difficult to handle. You can use ADO.NET Datasets to read and write data as XML. dataset.writexml and dataset.readxml will help you.

Comment: is it possible to show some examples here or have a link to an example as i was unable to find any example that suit my requirement online